# When implementing a MVC, which part of out application should call he methods in DAO?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, dao

I had exam today and one of the questions was the following:

> When implementing MVC, from which park of out web application (controller or view) we should call the methods defined in out DAO implementation? You should explain.

---

I know that the controller responsible of redirecting coming http request to the appropriate view,
and the views (JSP files) should use the DAOs function in order to get info and show it.

My lecturer says I've wrong and the controller take response of it.

When I asked why, he said that *"I should have listen in the lectures"*.
So again, why should the DAOs called from the controller and not from the view?

Comment: And what did your lecture notes say? Or the text books he recommended?

Comment: Someone nominated this for reopening, but I don't see on what grounds. A comment explaining the reasoning would be helpful. Otherwise, if this is reopened, I'll be too tempted to post as an answer "You should have listened in the lectures." :)

Answer (score 5):

You should have listened in the Lectures.

Sorry, just kidding :)

Model-View-Controller is an important design pattern used in all sorts of UI design.

- View is about displaying the data and interacting with the user - nothing else
- Model is about modelling and storing the data - nothing else
- Controller is what processes the data, mapping stuff in and out of the model, etc.

You should be able to swap the View from an MVC system completely and it will change the user interaction - but none of the behaviour of the program. From that it should be clear why putting logic in the View is a bad idea.

The DAO is about how you implement your data storage and persistence layer. The View is about how you display your data.

They are two very different jobs and the whole point of MVC is to split things up and give them their own independent jobs to do. You can swap in and out a different persistence layer and the view doesn't need to change, you can swap in and out different views and the persistence layer doesn't change.

By directly coupling presentation to persistence you lose that decoupling. The correct way to do it is write views that just care about the model. Write models that just care about their data and then use a controller to glue them together and to populate the model.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand .. can you please explain more detaily?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them. That would be answer to your question.

- MVC pattern is for the *presentation* layer only and has nothing with the persistence layer.
- DAO pattern is for *persistence* layer.

They are different patterns if applied to the web application.

Between these two layers should be a *service* layer.

The service layer holds all the business logic of the application interacting with the presentation and persistence layers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

DAO classes are used to access data from datasource like rdbms,xml etc.
Business object request data to be loaded from database through a DAO. DAO does the actual loading of data by using sql queries. 
Business object represent actual data eg: EmployeeBO. DAO classes like EmployeeDAO abstracts the underlying database access logic for business object. This promotes decoupling.

Servlet which is a controller may create a EmployeeBO, store data sent by the user in EmployeeBO. EmployeeBO use the DAO EmployeeDAO to store or read data from database and send back to servlet and the servlet passes the data back to jSP again.  So servlet uses the DAO and not the JSP.

The whole point is DAO pattern.